# Google maps API Basic Example

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been unable to get the basic Google maps example working on my site.  I have the following div on my page:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

And the following in the head of my document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    }
    jQuery(document).ready(initialize);
</script>
```

It appears that the elements are getting loaded into my DOM, but there is no visible map on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Google Map not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960056/google-map-not-showing-up), it appears that percentage sizes on the div (e.g. 100%) don't work properly. I had to explicitly specify a pixel height and width for the div.

Comment: To quote Mike Williams online resource -- http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm -- "If you try to use style="width:100%;height:100%" on your map div, you get a map div that has zero height. That's because the div tries to be a percentage of the size of the <body>, but by default the <body> has an indeterminate height[...] a simple alternative is to change the <body> so that its height is 100% of the page."

Answer (score 1):

Use 100% only if you want to show google map on the whole screen..!!
Here is a sample which used 100% width height
http://www.rizeworkshop.com/basic-google-map-v3/

Answer (score 0):

You have jQuery enabled on your site? Otherwise, within your body-tag create a "onload=initialize();"-attribut so that the javascript will be executed.

As far as I know your inital-request needs an API key?

Comment: Yes, I have jQuery enabled. The initialize() function is getting called when the document loads. The API key is part of the old Version 2 Google Maps API and is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

the code looks ok and it's similar to the examples from the documentation so it should be working properly.

Have you tried printing some information on the screen from the initialize function? Check if the latlng, myoptions and map variables are created correctly.

If they are, there's a problem with calling the initialize function...

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and iw works fine if i use `<body onload="initialize()">` as da_didi suggested.
Do you have an import directive for jquery.js?

Comment: Yes, jQuery is imported and working correctly. As I mentioned in the OP and as a comment to da_didi, the initialize function is getting called and it appears that some elements are getting loaded into the div

Comment: Maybe you can edit your post and include the entire code for us to help.Or upload it to the net and point us to it