# google maps fullscreen

Tags: css, google-maps

Im trying to get google maps to show 100% width and height. I have search several examples but cannot get it to work. The page it here

http://o-meter.dk/geo2.html

I used this css in the head

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body { height:100%; }
</style>
```

and this in the map div inline

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%;">indenfor</div>
```

The map dosnt show

If i do this instead

```
<div id="map" style="width:500px; height:500px;">indenfor</div>
```

then the maps shows in 500x500 pixels.

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Link in the question is now broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map needs both a height and a width.

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body { height:100%; width:100%;}
</style>
```

Comment: i solved it with:

    #map {    height : 100%;
    width : 100%;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
    position : absolute;
    z-index : 200;

Comment: This solution creates small horizontal and vertical scrolls

Answer (score 10):

I used the following css:

```
#map_canvas {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `min-height: 100%` on the style of the map `div`.

http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/

If that doesn't work, you could also get the width and height of the window in Javascript and then set the style on the map element dynamically to meet those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra style-tag, remove it:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
<style type="text/css">
html, body { height:100%; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you solved it with

```
#map { height : 100%; width : 100%; top : 0; left : 0; position : absolute; z-index : 200;}
```

It works because `map` has no parent with `position:relative`, so the it's relatively positioned to the window.

But if you want `map` to be relatively positioned to the window even if it has a parent with `position:relative`, you should use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`.

Moreover, you don't have to use so huge `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

In the below example, applying `style="height: 100%;"` to the `body` and `html` makes google maps full height because the `div` the map loads in to is a child of `body`.  In your case, you need to add `style="height: 100%;"` to the relevant parent elements of `#map`.

Related:

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm

[Google maps API Basic Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431453/google-maps-api-basic-example/4442786#4442786)